# Can not call method of the PHP class

Tags: php, html

I have a simple simple question ! :-D
I am brand new to `Php`, i wrote a simple `code` so I can connect to a device via `SSH`.
But when i try this in a class and method, does not work.
Here is my code of the main Php that includes my class too  :

```php
<?php
class Connection {
    public $ip;
    public $usernam;
    public $password;
    public  $ssh;

    public  function sshConnection() {

        include ('./view/login.html');
        include('Net/SSH2.php'); // I use phpseclib to connect via SSH
        if(isset($_POST['login'])) { // Login button in html file


            $this->ip = $_POST['ip']; // input type to get ip in html file
            $this->usernam = $_POST['username']; // input type to get username in html file
            $this->password = $_POST['password']; // input type to get password in html file
            $this->ssh = new Net_SSH2($ip);
            if (!$ssh->login($username, $password)) {

                print('Login faild');
            } else {
                echo $ssh->exec('pwd');

            }
        }
    }
}


$connection=new Connection();

$connection->sshConnection();
```

The `html` file login.`html` that I have included is the view of the login page with some internal `CSS`.
As you see i have created a class by this code :

```php
$connection=new Connection();       
$connection->sshConnection();
```

When I use this codes without creating classes it works fine !
As I define class it does not work and nothing happen after I press Login Button.

Where I am doing wrong?
Any help will appreciate. :-)

Comment: Why are you using `if(isset($_POST['login'])) {` inside the class/function?
Are you also using it outside the class?

Comment: You can place your include statements outside of class

Comment: @Echoes : No, I do not use this outside of the class.
Just inside the class.

Comment: @zenwraight : When I put includes outside of the class and after <?php code, the html page that is another directory ( In view file ) does not load and display blank page.

Comment: You have a lot of undefined variables in this code. Why you are using $ssh when one line above your are assigning value to $this->ssh not to $ssh. Same for $username, $password. You have also typo in public $usernam;

Comment: @arbogastes : Thats the point Bro.
Thats the point.
You can answer the question and I mark that.
Such a Stupid question !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, as I said in comment, your code should look like this (I've added a little bonus - isset() can check many variables in single call):

```
<?php
class Connection {
    public $ip;
    public $username;
    public $password;
    public $ssh;

    public  function sshConnection() {
        include ('./view/login.html');
        include('Net/SSH2.php'); // I use phpseclib to connect via SSH

        if(isset($_POST['login'], $_POST['ip'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) { // Login button in html file
            $this->ip = $_POST['ip']; // input type to get ip in html file
            $this->username = $_POST['username']; // input type to get username in html file
            $this->password = $_POST['password']; // input type to get password in html file
            $this->ssh = new Net_SSH2($this->ip);
            if (!$this->ssh->login($this->username, $this->password)) {
                print('Login faild');
            } else {
                echo $this->ssh->exec('pwd');

            }
        }
    }
}


$connection=new Connection();
$connection->sshConnection();
```

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to my friend @arbogastes, my question was very simple !
I forgot to add $this for all variables I had defined.
And Also thanks to @Echoes  and @zenwraight.
So my code went in this way :

```
<?php
             class Connection {
             public $ip;
             public $usernam;
             public $password;
             public  $ssh;

            public  function sshConnection() {

                include ('./view/login.html');
                include('Net/SSH2.php'); // I use phpseclib to connect via SSH
                if(isset($_POST['login'])) { // Login button in html file



             $this->ip = $_POST['ip'];
             $this->usernam = $_POST['username'];
             $this->password = $_POST['password'];
             $this->ssh = new Net_SSH2($this->ip);
            if (!$this->ssh->login($this->username, $this->password)) {
            exit('Login Failed');
            print('Login faild');
        } else {
        echo $ssh->exec('pwd');

        }
         }
           }
         }

         $connection=new Connection();

         $connection->sshConnection();
?>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
<?php
class Connection {
    public $ip;
    public $usernam;
    public $password;
    public  $ssh;

    public function sshConnection($ip, $username, $password) {
        include ('./view/login.html');
        include('Net/SSH2.php'); 

        $this->ip = $ip; // input type to get ip in html file
        $this->usernam = $username; // input type to get username in html file
        $this->password = $password; // input type to get password in html file
        $this->ssh = new Net_SSH2($this->ip); 
        if (!$this->ssh->login($this->usernam, $this->password)) {
            print('Login faild');
        } 
        else {
            echo $this->ssh->exec('pwd');
        }
    }
}

if(isset($_POST['login'])) {
    $connection=new Connection();
    $connection->sshConnection($_POST['ip'], $_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);
}

?>
```